# What is the purpose of throwing exceptions in pure functions?

Tags: haskell

Since the main source of non-deterministic exceptions is IO and you can catch exception only inside IO monad, it seams reasonable not to throw exceptions from pure functions.

Indeed what could so "exceptional" happen in a pure function? Empty list or division by zero are not really exceptional and can be expected. So why not use only `Maybe`, `Either` or `[]` to represent such cases in pure code.

There is a number of pure functions like `(!!)`, `tail`, `div` which do throw exceptions. What is the reason for making them unsafe?

Comment: I guess it's historical reasons - but your guess is as good as mine - of course you can argue that in each of these cases the behavior is exceptional and you should take care that it will never happen (I surely would not want to use `Maybe` everywhere I use `div`, `mod`, etc. ... that would be ugly and horrible to work with - `tail` is fine to similar reasons too (of course usually you don't need it) - and there are safe versions around

Comment: The haskell 2010 report makes no mention of non-IO exceptions (i.e. there is no pattern match failure exception, no `ErrorCall` exception, etc). In the report `error` is a primitive, with no real specific semantics other than those given by its type. Presumably GHC tries to comply with the report (historically and now), but it also provides a lot of added functionality (i.e. extensible exceptions). It makes sense to actually implement `error` as throwing an `ErrorCall` exception as opposed to inventing a brand new "error" mechanism simply for the `error` function.

Answer (score 6):

The unsafe functions are all examples of *partial* functions; they aren't defined for every value in their domain. Consider `head :: [a] -> a`. Its domain is `[a]`, but `head` is not defined for `[]`: there is no value of type `a` that would be correct to return. Something like `safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a` is a *total* function, because you can return a valid `Maybe a` for any list; `safeHead [] = Nothing`, and `safeHead (x:xs) = Just x`.

Ideally, your program would consist only of total functions, but in practice that isn't always possible. (Perhaps there are too many undefined values to anticipate, or you can't know ahead of time which values cause problems.) The exception is an obvious indication that your program is not well defined. When you get an exception, it means you need to change your code to either

1. Avoid calling the function on the value for which it is not defined
2. Replace your function with a function that *is* defined on the problem value.

Under no circumstances should "3. Continue running with an undefined value in place of the return value of your function" be considered acceptable.

(Some conjecture to follow, but I believe it is mostly correct.) Historically, Haskell didn't have a good way of handling exceptions. It was probably easier to check if a list were empty before calling `head :: [a] -> a` than to deal with a return value like `Maybe a`. That became less of an issue once monads were introduced, which provided a generic framework for feeding the output of `safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a` to functions of type `a -> b`. Given that it is easy to recognize that `head []` is not defined, it is at least simple to provide a helpful, specific error message than to rely on the generic error message. Now that functions like `safeHead` are easier to work with, functions like `head` can be considered historical relics rather than a model to emulate.

Comment: Hm. That raises a good point that I'm not sure how to address. Haskell can detect some such partial functions; `head []`, for instance, explicitly raises an "empty list" exception rather than a generic "Non-exhaustive patterns" exception. The OP is probably asking why `head :: [a] -> a` is defined at all, rather than only providing `head :: [a] -> Maybe a`. (Oops, the comment this was in response to has been deleted.)

Comment: I wouldn't consider a program made only (or most) of total functions a practical impossibility. From what is posted on SO, beginners quickly tend to resort to partial functions when there is no need to. Partiality should not be completely ruled out, yet it should be used with deep care, and only when safe alternatives are unsatisfactory. In my own opinion, `head` has very few uses I would approve or recommend. Instead, while `div` is partial, I find it reasonable.

Comment: I think that's partly due to the lack of dependent types (I think that's the term I mean here.) While it's not(?) impossible to define a type representing non-zero integers, it's far easier to define a function that stays undefined for a zero divisor.

Comment: (I'm also starting to think I would downvote this answer as being too opinion-based.)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, something that is *true* about how a program behaves is not *provable* within its source language. Other times, it may be provable, but not *efficiently* so. Still other times, it may be provable, but proving it would require a tremendous amount of time and effort on the part of the programmer.

#### An example

`Data.Sequence` represents sequences as size-annotated finger trees. It maintains the invariant that the number of elements in any subtree equals the annotation stored in its root. The implementation of `zipWith` for sequences splits the longer sequence to match the length of the shorter one, then uses an efficient, operationally lazy technique to zip them together.

This technique involves splitting the second sequence multiple times along the natural structure of the first sequence. When it reaches a leaf of the first sequence, it relies on the associated fragment of the second sequence having exactly one element. This is guaranteed to happen as long as the annotation invariant is maintained. If this invariant fails, `zipWith` has no option but to throw an error.

To encode the annotation invariant in Haskell, you'd need to index the underlying pieces of finger tree with their lengths. You'd then need each operation to *prove* that it maintains the invariant. This sort of thing is possible, and languages like Coq, Agda, and Idris try to reduce the pain and inefficiency. But they still have pain, and sometimes massive inefficiency. Haskell isn't really properly set up for such work as yet, and may never be great for it (that's just not its main goal as a language). It would be extremely painful, and also extremely inefficient. Since efficiency was the reason for choosing this implementation in the first place, that's just not an option.

Answer (score 3):

Certain functions have preconditions associated to them (`!!` requires a valid index, `tail` requires non-empty list, `div` requires non-zero divisor). A violation of a precondition should result in an exception, because you did not obey the contract.

The alternative is to not use preconditions, but to use a return value that indicates whether the call succeeded or not.

These are all core functions, so they need to be simple to use, which is a big point in favour of preconditions with exceptions. They are also pure, so there is never a surprise when they fail: you know exactly when that will happen, namely when you pass arguments that violate the preconditions. But, in the end, it comes down to a design choice, with points in favour and against both solutions.

Comment: There is a third alternative: choose the argument type(s) to _only contain values that fulfill the precondition_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: If you want Agda, you know where to find it.  (What is the type of `tail . tail . tail . tail . tail . tail` in that case?)